# Transformation of JSON file per field

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file in this format :

```
[
    {"itemId": "1", "score": 0.2, "userId": "1", "rank": 1}, 
    {"itemId": "3", "score": 0.1, "userId": "1", "rank": 2}, 
    {"itemId": "12", "score": 0.6, "userId": "2", "rank": 1}, 
    {"itemId": "21", "score": 0.2, "userId": "2", "rank": 2}, 
    ...
]
```

and I would like to sort it by userId like this :

```
{
    {
        "userId": "1",
        "items": [
            {"itemId": "1", "score": 0.2, "rank": 1},
            {"itemId": "3", "score": 0.1, "rank": 2},
            ...
        ]
    },

    {
        "userId": "2",
        "items": [
            {"itemId": "12", "score": 0.6, "rank": 1},
            {"itemId": "21", "score": 0.2, "rank": 2}
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

I tried to do it by myself with Python but I get an error that says : "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'".

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: JSON gets decoded into a dict in python and dicts don't have order. Try moving the data to an OrderedDict or just sort them right before using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accumulate the items in a `defaultdict(list)`, re-keying off the user ids:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {"itemId": "1", "score": 0.2, "userId": "1", "rank": 1}, 
    {"itemId": "3", "score": 0.1, "userId": "1", "rank": 2}, 
    {"itemId": "12", "score": 0.6, "userId": "2", "rank": 1}, 
    {"itemId": "21", "score": 0.2, "userId": "2", "rank": 2}, 
]

output = defaultdict(list)
for dict_ in data:
    userId = dict_.pop('userId')
    output[int(userId)].append(dict_)

new_data = [{'userId': str(k), 'items': output[k]} for k in sorted(output)]
```

Comment: It inverts the order between userId and items but that is not a big deal. Thank you for the answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `pandas` to load and then use `groupby` and `sort`. Then write back to json in the way you want. See below:

```
data = '[{"itemId": "1", "score": 0.2, "userId": "1", "rank": 1}, {"itemId": "12", "score": 0.6, "userId": "2", "rank": 1},  {"itemId": "3", "score": 0.1, "userId": "1", "rank": 2},  {"itemId": "21", "score": 0.2, "userId": "2", "rank": 2}]'


import pandas as pd
import collections

# read the json file to pandas
df = pd.read_json(data, dtype = {"itemId":object, "score": object, "userId": object, "rank":int})
# group by user id and sort them
g = df.groupby(['userId'],sort=True)

mylist = []
for k in g.groups.keys():
    # create a temp dict holder
    temp_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    #populate teh temp dict
    temp_dict['userId'] = k
    temp_dict['items'] = g['itemId','rank', 'score'].get_group(k).to_dict(orient='records')
    # add the temp dict to the list
    mylist.append(temp_dict)

# print as json
import json
print json.dumps(mylist,indent=4)
```

this will result in

```
[
    {
        "userId": "1", 
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": "1", 
                "score": 0.2, 
                "rank": 1
            }, 
            {
                "itemId": "3", 
                "score": 0.1, 
                "rank": 2
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "userId": "2", 
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": "12", 
                "score": 0.6000000000000001, 
                "rank": 1
            }, 
            {
                "itemId": "21", 
                "score": 0.2, 
                "rank": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have a problem with the line : `df = pd.read_json(data, dtype = {'itemId':object, 'score': object, 'userId': object, 'rank':int})` that throws the error : `TypeError: Expected String or Unicode`. An idea ?

Comment: Glad to help. This error is happening because one of your variables datatype may not be correct. you could change this line to df = pd.read_json(data), in this case, it will automatically identify the datatype for each column. let me know if that fixes it.